# OpenGL functions fails in multithread application

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, mutex, semaphore

Why **sometimes** after the next calls:

```
TakeOpenGL();
glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH, &TextureWidth);
glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, &TextureHeight);
FreeOpenGL();
```

variables Texture* have incorrect values?

Im using OpenGL mutex, which doing the next:

```
void TakeOpenGL(){
    OpenGL.Enter();
    wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC);
}

void FreeOpenGL(){
    OpenGL.Leave();
    wglMakeCurrent(0, 0);
}
```

What problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call `wglMakeCurrent` without holding the mutex. Your `FreeOpenGL` function does this.